# Issue compiling c++ in c++builder

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder

I have written a C++ program for a University assignment. I used Netbeans 6.8 running on my Mac and the code runs smoothly, no warnings, errors or problems/bugs. However when compiling and running on a Windows computer using CodeGear RAD Studio 2009 (C++ Builder) am getting several errors.

```
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(51): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(62): E2093 'operator==' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of the same type
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(67): E2093 'operator==' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of the same type
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(112): E2093 'operator==' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of the same type
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(121): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(130): E2093 'operator==' not implemented in type 'string' for arguments of the same type
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(133): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(139): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(153): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'fstream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(199): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'fstream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(219): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'istream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(231): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'istream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(240): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'istream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(262): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'istream' for arguments of type 'string'
[BCC32 Error] main.cpp(264): E2094 'operator>>' not implemented in type 'istream' for arguments of type 'string'
```

---

These are the header files am using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio>
#include <windows> //I added this one just to check and still does not work (I didnt have it on Netbeans/Mac)
using namespace std;
```

---

Any ideas what is producing the errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Wild guess: you need `#include <string>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need:

```
#include <string>
```

and it's:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

though I doubt you need it.

The reason your code worked on one platform but not another is that on the first platform one of the other library headers was including `<string>` itself. This behaviour is not specified by the C++ Standard, so the only safe rule is:

> If you use a class or a function,
>   always explicitly #include the header
>   for that class or function in your
>   code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on `string` object :

```
to_string < char,std::string::traits_type,std::string::allocator_type>()
```