# C++Builder compile issue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder, event-log

This is a follow-up question to this question I asked earlier. Btw thanks Neil Butterworth for your help
[Issue compiling c++ in c++builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461977/problem-compiling-c-in-codegear)

---

A quick recap. I'm currently developing a C++ program for university, I used Netbeans 6.8 on my personal computer (Mac) and it all works perfect. When I try them on my windows partition or at the university PC's using C++Builder 2009 & 2010 I was getting a few compile errors which were solved by adding the following header file:

```
#include <string>
```

However now the program does compile but it doesn't run, just a blank console. And am getting the following in the compiler's event log:

```
Thread Start: Thread ID: 2024. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Process Start: C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Debug\Project1.exe. Base Address: $00400000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: Project1.exe. Has Debug Info. Base Address: $00400000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: ntdll.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77E80000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: KERNEL32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $771C0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: KERNELBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75FE0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: cc32100.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $32A00000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: USER32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77980000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: GDI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75F50000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: LPK.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75AB0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: USP10.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $76030000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: msvcrt.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $776A0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: ADVAPI32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $777D0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: SECHOST.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $77960000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: RPCRT4.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $762F0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: SspiCli.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $759F0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: CRYPTBASE.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $759E0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: IMM32.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $763F0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
Module Load: MSCTF.dll. No Debug Info. Base Address: $75AD0000. Process Project1.exe (3280)
```

---

I would really appreciate any help or ideas on how to solve this problem.

**P.S:** In the case anyone wonders why am I sticking with C++Builder is because it is the IDE professors use to evaluate our assignments.

Comment: As much as i know Codegear (past Borland) has its own compiler so that usually can be quite a bit problem. Did you try to run your program in debug mode? Where does it stop?

Comment: @Adi: it doesn't stop. 
"Checking project dependencies..."
"Compiling Project1.cbproj (Debug configuration)"
"Success"

Comment: Ok. But did you try to put a breakpoint somewhere in the beginning of the code, such as in FormCreate() event or in main() function?

Comment: The console output is useless, it simply tells you that Windows' DLL's do not have debug info, which makes total sense.  Other than that you're basically saying `my program does not work` and oh I'm not posting any code. Voting to close.

Comment: The console output is useless, it simply tells you that Windows' DLL's do not have debug info, which makes total sense.  Other than that you're basically saying `my program does not work` and oh I'm not posting any code. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have debugging enabled, 
and you can't even step into main() with the debugger (Pressing [F7] or [F8]),
like the program is crashing before it even gets into main.
This could be a problem if you have a global (or static) instance of an object, and the object's constructor code is crashing.

If you do have a global object I.e.

```
MyClass object;
int main()
{ .... };
```

Try dynamically allocating it in main().

```
MyClass *object = 0;
int main()
{ object = new MyClass;
....
};
```